# Get linked info from Mysql in one request

Tags: mysql

I gather info from my customer with a regular query:

```
select `ip`, `firstname`, `lastname` from `applications` where `pin` = '2232'
```

Is it possible to get also all the record that matches the customer ip in table from one pin number?

Example, one customer have one pin number, i make a request on this pin number and it returns me not only the info linked to this pin number but also the info from all other customer that used the same ip of the first customer.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is called a "join" query. Any basic SQL tutorial will talk about joins.

Comment: @Greg this seems more like a sub-query situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ip, firstname, lastname from applications where pin = '2232' OR 
ip in (select ip from applications where pin = '2232')
```

Probably a way to do this without two selects, but this will work.

Comment: thanks! this works for me :) actually with ip in (...) i get a timeout so I use instead ip = (...) . I don't know if it's right but it works :)

Comment: Actually, as the second select will take also the one with only the pin I do this now: 
    select ip, firstname, lastname from applications where  ip = (select ip from applications where pin = '2232')